# What is the techno music that plays in the film "Play or Die"?

Tags: music-identification, play-or-die

What is the techno music that plays in the Belgian movie *Play or Die* (2019) when Lucas and Chloe arrive to the rave party?

Answer (score 1):

The closing credits list "Olympix", composed and written by Luc Mourinet (also known as [Luke Mornay](https://lukemornay.com/2019/03/play-or-die-film/)). I haven't been able to find a sample of this track though, so I don't know if this is the techno music at the rave party scene.

Comment: This answer (without an actual confirmation that this is the correct track) feels more like a comment.

Comment: This is a sample of [Olympix](https://www.genie.co.kr/search/searchMain?query=olympix) by Soultraderz (with Luc Mourinet). It doesn't sound *very* similar to the music in the film

Comment: Listen at 13:08 when they are in the club. It's hard to compare a remix, but I'd say they were similar.

Comment: I'm trying to get hold of the original

Comment: It seems this is it. It remains only wait the moment when the track "Olympix" by Luc Mourinet will be available.

Comment: Could be just one more remix by Luc Mourinet